# Must an irreducible polynomial over a field extension divide the irreducible polynomial over the subfield?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $k \subset E$ be a field extension, and let $\alpha$ be algebraic over $k$. Let $f$ be the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k$, and let $g$ be the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E$. Is it true that $g$ always divides $f$?

Comment: It is true. It follows directly from the fact, that polynomial rings over fields are PIDs.